# storing data in ORM-Lite Android gives SqlException

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlexception

please bare for any mistakes this is my first time on stackoverflow

**DAO class**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    // name of the database file for your application -- change to something
    // appropriate for your app
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "fieldsense.db";
    // any time you make changes to your database objects, you may have to
    // increase the database version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // the DAO object we use to access the Appointments table
    private Dao<Appointments, Integer> simpleDao = null;
    private RuntimeExceptionDao<Appointments, Integer> simpleRuntimeDao = null;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION,
                R.raw.ormlite_config);
    }

    /**
     * This is called when the database is first created. Usually you should
     * call createTable statements here to create the tables that will store
     * your data.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try {
            Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onCreate");
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Appointments.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Time.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Customer.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't create database", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // here we try inserting data in the on-create as a test
        RuntimeExceptionDao<Appointments, Integer> dao = getSimpleDataDao();
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // create some entries in the onCreate

        Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
                "created new entries in onCreate: " + millis);
    }

    /**
     * This is called when your application is upgraded and it has a higher
     * version number. This allows you to adjust the various data to match the
     * new version number.
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource,
            int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onUpgrade");
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Appointments.class, true);
            // after we drop the old databases, we create the new ones
            onCreate(db, connectionSource);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't drop databases", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Database Access Object (DAO) for our Appointments class. It
     * will create it or just give the cached value.
     */
    public Dao<Appointments, Integer> getDao() throws SQLException {
        if (simpleDao == null) {
            simpleDao = getDao(Appointments.class);
        }
        return simpleDao;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the RuntimeExceptionDao (Database Access Object) version of a Dao
     * for our Appointments class. It will create it or just give the cached
     * value. RuntimeExceptionDao only through RuntimeExceptions.
     */
    public RuntimeExceptionDao<Appointments, Integer> getSimpleDataDao() {
        if (simpleRuntimeDao == null) {
            simpleRuntimeDao = getRuntimeExceptionDao(Appointments.class);
        }
        return simpleRuntimeDao;
    }

    /**
     * Close the database connections and clear any cached DAOs.
     */
    @Override
    public void close() {
        super.close();
        simpleDao = null;
        simpleRuntimeDao = null;
    }
```

**Appointment Model class**

```
package in.qlc.model;

import android.util.Log;

public class Appointments {

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Time appointmentTime;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Time createdOn;
    @DatabaseField
    private int cretedById;

    public Time getAppointmentTime() {
        return appointmentTime;
    }

    public void setAppointmentTime(Time appointmentTime) {
        this.appointmentTime = appointmentTime;
    }

    public Time getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Time createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true,foreignAutoCreate = true,foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Customer customer;
    @DatabaseField
    private int outcomeId;
    @DatabaseField
    private int purposeId;
    @DatabaseField
    private int userId;

    public int getCretedById() {
        return cretedById;
    }

    public void setCretedById(int cretedById) {
        this.cretedById = cretedById;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getOutcomeId() {
        return outcomeId;
    }

    public void setOutcomeId(int outcomeId) {
        this.outcomeId = outcomeId;
    }

    public int getPurposeId() {
        return purposeId;
    }

    public void setPurposeId(int purposeId) {
        this.purposeId = purposeId;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }    
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
package in.qlc.model;    
import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;

public class Customer {

    // private Time createdOn;

    public Customer() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [customerAddress1=" + customerAddress1
                + ", customerAddress2=" + customerAddress2
                + ", customerAddress3=" + customerAddress3 + ", customerCity="
                + customerCity + ", customerCountry=" + customerCountry
                + ", customerEmail1=" + customerEmail1 + ", customerEmail2="
                + customerEmail2 + ", customerEmail3=" + customerEmail3
                + ", customerFax1=" + customerFax1 + ", customerFax2="
                + customerFax2 + ", customerLocation=" + customerLocation
                + ", customerName=" + customerName + ", customerPhone1="
                + customerPhone1 + ", customerPhone2=" + customerPhone2
                + ", customerPhone3=" + customerPhone3 + ", customerPrintas="
                + customerPrintas + ", customerState=" + customerState
                + ", customerWebsiteUrl1=" + customerWebsiteUrl1
                + ", customerWebsiteUrl2=" + customerWebsiteUrl2
                + ", customerZipcode=" + customerZipcode + ", id=" + id
                + ", industry=" + industry + ", isHeadOffice=" + isHeadOffice
                + ", territory=" + territory + "]";
    }

    @DatabaseField
    private String customerAddress1;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerAddress2;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerAddress3;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerCity;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerCountry;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerEmail1;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerEmail2;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerEmail3;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerFax1;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerFax2;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerLocation;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerName;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerPhone1;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerPhone2;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerPhone3;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerPrintas;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerState;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerWebsiteUrl1;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerWebsiteUrl2;
    @DatabaseField
    private String customerZipcode;
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String industry;
    @DatabaseField
    private boolean isHeadOffice;
    @DatabaseField
    private String territory;

    // public Time getCreatedOn() {
    // return createdOn;
    // }
    //
    // public void setCreatedOn(Time createdOn) {
    // this.createdOn = createdOn;
    // }

    public String getCustomerAddress1() {
        return customerAddress1;
    }

    public void setCustomerAddress1(String customerAddress1) {
        this.customerAddress1 = customerAddress1;
    }

    public String getCustomerAddress2() {
        return customerAddress2;
    }

    public void setCustomerAddress2(String customerAddress2) {
        this.customerAddress2 = customerAddress2;
    }

    public String getCustomerAddress3() {
        return customerAddress3;
    }

    public void setCustomerAddress3(String customerAddress3) {
        this.customerAddress3 = customerAddress3;
    }

    public String getCustomerCity() {
        return customerCity;
    }

    public void setCustomerCity(String customerCity) {
        this.customerCity = customerCity;
    }

    public String getCustomerCountry() {
        return customerCountry;
    }

    public void setCustomerCountry(String customerCountry) {
        this.customerCountry = customerCountry;
    }

    public String getCustomerEmail1() {
        return customerEmail1;
    }

    public void setCustomerEmail1(String customerEmail1) {
        this.customerEmail1 = customerEmail1;
    }

    public String getCustomerEmail2() {
        return customerEmail2;
    }

    public void setCustomerEmail2(String customerEmail2) {
        this.customerEmail2 = customerEmail2;
    }

    public String getCustomerEmail3() {
        return customerEmail3;
    }

    public void setCustomerEmail3(String customerEmail3) {
        this.customerEmail3 = customerEmail3;
    }

    public String getCustomerFax1() {
        return customerFax1;
    }

    public void setCustomerFax1(String customerFax1) {
        this.customerFax1 = customerFax1;
    }

    public String getCustomerFax2() {
        return customerFax2;
    }

    public void setCustomerFax2(String customerFax2) {
        this.customerFax2 = customerFax2;
    }

    public String getCustomerLocation() {
        return customerLocation;
    }

    public void setCustomerLocation(String customerLocation) {
        this.customerLocation = customerLocation;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getCustomerPhone1() {
        return customerPhone1;
    }

    public void setCustomerPhone1(String customerPhone1) {
        this.customerPhone1 = customerPhone1;
    }

    public String getCustomerPhone2() {
        return customerPhone2;
    }

    public void setCustomerPhone2(String customerPhone2) {
        this.customerPhone2 = customerPhone2;
    }

    public String getCustomerPhone3() {
        return customerPhone3;
    }

    public void setCustomerPhone3(String customerPhone3) {
        this.customerPhone3 = customerPhone3;
    }

    public String getCustomerPrintas() {
        return customerPrintas;
    }

    public void setCustomerPrintas(String customerPrintas) {
        this.customerPrintas = customerPrintas;
    }

    public String getCustomerState() {
        return customerState;
    }

    public void setCustomerState(String customerState) {
        this.customerState = customerState;
    }

    public String getCustomerWebsiteUrl1() {
        return customerWebsiteUrl1;
    }

    public void setCustomerWebsiteUrl1(String customerWebsiteUrl1) {
        this.customerWebsiteUrl1 = customerWebsiteUrl1;
    }

    public String getCustomerWebsiteUrl2() {
        return customerWebsiteUrl2;
    }

    public void setCustomerWebsiteUrl2(String customerWebsiteUrl2) {
        this.customerWebsiteUrl2 = customerWebsiteUrl2;
    }

    public String getCustomerZipcode() {
        return customerZipcode;
    }

    public void setCustomerZipcode(String customerZipcode) {
        this.customerZipcode = customerZipcode;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIndustry() {
        return industry;
    }

    public void setIndustry(String industry) {
        this.industry = industry;
    }

    public boolean isHeadOffice() {
        return isHeadOffice;
    }

    public void setHeadOffice(boolean isHeadOffice) {
        this.isHeadOffice = isHeadOffice;
    }

    public String getTerritory() {
        return territory;
    }

    public void setTerritory(String territory) {
        this.territory = territory;
    }
}
```

**Time.java**

```
public class Time {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Time [date=" + date + ", day=" + day + ", hours=" + hours
                + ", minutes=" + minutes + ", month=" + month + ", nanos="
                + nanos + ", seconds=" + seconds + ", time=" + time
                + ", timezoneOffset=" + timezoneOffset + ", year=" + year
                + ", dbid=" + dbid + "]";
    }

    public Time() {
    }

    @DatabaseField
    private int date;
    @DatabaseField
    private int day;
    @DatabaseField
    private int hours;
    @DatabaseField
    private int minutes;
    @DatabaseField
    private int month;
    @DatabaseField
    private int nanos;
    @DatabaseField
    private int seconds;
    @DatabaseField
    private long time;
    @DatabaseField
    private int timezoneOffset;
    @DatabaseField
    private int year;

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int dbid;

    public int getId() {
        return dbid;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.dbid = id;
    }

    public int getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(int date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(int hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getNanos() {
        return nanos;
    }

    public void setNanos(int nanos) {
        this.nanos = nanos;
    }

    public int getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    public void setSeconds(int seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getTimezoneOffset() {
        return timezoneOffset;
    }

    public void setTimezoneOffset(int timezoneOffset) {
        this.timezoneOffset = timezoneOffset;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

}
```

Main code to call

```
 private void doSampleDatabaseStuff(List<Appointments> appoint) {
        // get our dao
        RuntimeExceptionDao<Appointments, Integer> appointDao = getHelper()
                .getSimpleDataDao();



        for (Iterator iterator = appoint.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Appointments appointments = (Appointments) iterator.next();
            int create = appointDao.create(appointments);
            Log.e(TAG," create "+ create);
        }
```

Error

```
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object in.qlc.model.Appointments@406fff00: INSERT INTO `appointments` (`appointmentTime_id` ,`createdOn_id` ,`cretedById` ,`id` ,`customer_id` ,`outcomeId` ,`purposeId` ,`userId` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.RuntimeExceptionDao.create(RuntimeExceptionDao.java:228)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at in.qlc.fragments.SlideUpFragment.doSampleDatabaseStuff(SlideUpFragment.java:256)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at in.qlc.fragments.SlideUpFragment.access$0(SlideUpFragment.java:247)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at in.qlc.fragments.SlideUpFragment$GetTask.onPostExecute(SlideUpFragment.java:225)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at in.qlc.fragments.SlideUpFragment$GetTask.onPostExecute(SlideUpFragment.java:1)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931): Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object in.qlc.model.Appointments@406fff00: INSERT INTO `appointments` (`appointmentTime_id` ,`createdOn_id` ,`cretedById` ,`id` ,`customer_id` ,`outcomeId` ,`purposeId` ,`userId` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:124)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:394)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:308)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.RuntimeExceptionDao.create(RuntimeExceptionDao.java:225)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    ... 15 more
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931): Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object Time [date=26, day=3, hours=5, minutes=30, month=1, nanos=0, seconds=0, time=1393372800000, timezoneOffset=-330, year=114, dbid=0]: INSERT INTO `time` (`date` ,`day` ,`hours` ,`minutes` ,`month` ,`nanos` ,`seconds` ,`time` ,`timezoneOffset` ,`year` ,`dbid` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:124)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:394)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:308)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.createWithForeignDao(FieldType.java:916)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:74)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    ... 18 more
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931): Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: inserting to database failed: INSERT INTO `time` (`date` ,`day` ,`hours` ,`minutes` ,`month` ,`nanos` ,`seconds` ,`time` ,`timezoneOffset` ,`year` ,`dbid` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.insert(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:152)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:89)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    ... 22 more
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.insert(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:140)
02-28 12:09:29.656: E/AndroidRuntime(27931):    ... 23 more


This was the create stament tha  i got in the logs

02-28 12:29:54.131: I/in.qlc.fieldsense.database.DatabaseHelper(3593): onCreate
02-28 12:29:54.151: I/TableUtils(3593): creating table 'appointments'
02-28 12:29:54.181: I/TableUtils(3593): executed create table statement changed 1 rows: CREATE TABLE `appointments` (`appointmentTime_id` INTEGER , `createdOn_id` INTEGER , `cretedById` INTEGER , `id` INTEGER , `customer_id` INTEGER , `outcomeId` INTEGER , `purposeId` INTEGER , `userId` INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) 
02-28 12:29:54.201: I/TableUtils(3593): creating table 'time'
02-28 12:29:54.201: I/TableUtils(3593): executed create table statement changed 1 rows: CREATE TABLE `time` (`date` INTEGER , `day` INTEGER , `hours` INTEGER , `minutes` INTEGER , `month` INTEGER , `nanos` INTEGER , `seconds` INTEGER , `time` BIGINT , `timezoneOffset` INTEGER , `year` INTEGER , `dbid` INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY (`dbid`) ) 
02-28 12:29:54.211: I/TableUtils(3593): creating table 'customer'
02-28 12:29:54.231: I/TableUtils(3593): executed create table statement changed 1 rows: CREATE TABLE `customer` (`customerAddress1` VARCHAR , `customerAddress2` VARCHAR , `customerAddress3` VARCHAR , `customerCity` VARCHAR , `customerCountry` VARCHAR , `customerEmail1` VARCHAR , `customerEmail2` VARCHAR , `customerEmail3` VARCHAR , `customerFax1` VARCHAR , `customerFax2` VARCHAR , `customerLocation` VARCHAR , `customerName` VARCHAR , `customerPhone1` VARCHAR , `customerPhone2` VARCHAR , `customerPhone3` VARCHAR , `customerPrintas` VARCHAR , `customerState` VARCHAR , `customerWebsiteUrl1` VARCHAR , `customerWebsiteUrl2` VARCHAR , `customerZipcode` VARCHAR , `id` INTEGER , `industry` VARCHAR , `isHeadOffice` SMALLINT , `territory` VARCHAR , PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) 
02-28 12:29:54.231: I/in.qlc.fieldsense.database.DatabaseHelper(3593): created new entries in onCreate: 1393570794244
```

Comment: Try to add canBeNull = true property to every DB field in your appointments table and then try.

Comment: no change I got the same error I just now posted the create table log please can you check that